# PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": "panic"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rubygems

rake db:create showing error PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": "panic"
HINT:  Available values: debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1, log, notice, warning, error.

After bundle install tried to run rake db:create commond.
Created database.yml file inside the config folder please find below :

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: thor_development1
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: thor_test1
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: localhost
```

```
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": "panic"
HINT:  Available values: debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1, log, notice, warning, error.
: SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:274:in `client_min_messages='
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:634:in `set_standard_conforming_strings'
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:914:in `configure_connection'
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:895:in `connect'
/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
```

Trying to install in macOS Catalina

Comment: Can you provide us with your `config/database.yml`?

Comment: Aurelien added database.yml code please check

Comment: I don't understand why your default `min_messages` is set to 'panic'. You can try to set `min_messages: notice` in development

Comment: code did not work :(

Comment: What is the error? Here is an example: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/235eb91bad58ab18b45aa36fa3a1ebedfe1c4879/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases/postgresql.yml.tt#L53

Answer (score 80):

To make it work with PostgreSQL version 12, I monkey patched PostgreSQLAdapter class to replace 'panic' with 'warning' message. 
Note, if you can upgrade activerecord gem to 4.2.6 or higher versions you don't need to have this monkey patch. I had to do this because my project depends on gem `activerecord-3.2.22.5`

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
  def set_standard_conforming_strings
    old, self.client_min_messages = client_min_messages, 'warning'
    execute('SET standard_conforming_strings = on', 'SCHEMA') rescue nil
  ensure
    self.client_min_messages = old
  end
end
```

Comment: @orberkov you need to create a new file. I named it as 'postgresql_adapter_monkeypatch.rb' and put it in the rails directory config/initializers/.

Comment: I am facing same issue while upgrading postgres 9.1 to 12(Rails 3). I tried using above patch in config/initializers, but i am getting error: "ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:133:in `establish_connection': database configuration specifies nonexistent postgresql adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotFound)"

Comment: @pooja it seems your activerecord gem is older version than what I described before. Try upgrading activerecord to v3.2.22.5 version and see if it helps.

Comment: @ruslan I've had the same `database configuration specifies nonexistent postgresql adapter` error on Heroku, so I also had to `require 'active_record/base'` before `require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'`.

Comment: Totally awesome, thanks! I would upvote this answer +100 if I could! This just saved us from having to upgrade/update a legacy Rails app in production that is about to be retired but needs a few more months runway to migrate customers. Sending some real-life Karma your way! :)

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same problem, and I finally figured out what it was.  I grepped for the word "panic" inside of my gems folder, and got a hit in my ActiveRecord 4.2.2 gem, line 313.  I monkey-patched the file, changing the value to "error", and I was then able to proceed with the db:create rake task.  It seems likely that the ActiveRecord gem was changed, or the pg gem was changed, even though I'm using old, specific versions of both, because I was able to run db:create a few weeks ago, but now couldn't without this hack.

TL;DR:

```
gem info pg
```

cd to the folder where it's installed (for me, ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems)

```
grep -ri 'panic' .
```

Replace anything related to pg with 'error' or some other valid message.

Comment: In my case the file I made changes is `...gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb` .

Comment: If someone is lost like i am, this answer worked for me. I have searched the `postgresql_adapter.rb` in  the `/.rvm/gems/` folder, opened the file in editor and just replaced the "panic" in `self.client_min_messages = client_min_messages, 'panic'` with "warning".

Answer (score 9):

In PostgreSQL 12 they [disallowed the `PANIC` value](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/3d360e20c9) for `client_min_messages`, that Rails was setting [since 2.3.14](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/29b0707f07f148d98515125dab44b73cfdc0a3d4#diff-2468c670eb10c24bd2823e42708489a336d6f21c6efc7e3c4a574166fa77bb22R295). That was fixed in [Rails 4.2.5](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8792f323da01d88c955ab4a85586724000eb8bfd).

As such upgrading Rails resolves the issue. A link to a [more detailed report](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/d76b487c49698cd80edd511ed58bfb81), for what it's worth.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into two problems with pg12 on old rails versions.  This file fixes both problems with ruby 1.8 and activerecord 3.0.3.  I put it in config/initializers/postgresql_adapter_pg12.rb

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
  def set_standard_conforming_strings
    old, self.client_min_messages = client_min_messages, 'warning'
    execute('SET standard_conforming_strings = on', 'SCHEMA') rescue nil
  ensure
    self.client_min_messages = old
  end

  def column_definitions(table_name) #:nodoc:
    query <<-end_sql
      SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull
        FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
          ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
       WHERE a.attrelid = '#{quote_table_name(table_name)}'::regclass
         AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
       ORDER BY a.attnum
    end_sql
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this saved me with a legacy app using active record 3.1.12. The extra column_definition patch seems to be required for versions that old.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Adding this I resolved the issue and now the app is connected to PostgreSQL 13.7 on Amazon Aurora..

Answer (score 7):

I needed to make the following modifications to the monkey patch from @ruslan to work with Rails 4.2.4:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class PostgreSQLAdapter
      def set_standard_conforming_strings
        old, self.client_min_messages = client_min_messages, 'warning'
        execute('SET standard_conforming_strings = on', 'SCHEMA') rescue nil
      ensure
        self.client_min_messages = old
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue with Postgres 12.1 and I need to roll back to 9.4 and was solved.

Comment: I am using ruby 1.9.3 with rails v 3+, and based on your comment I realized that it is in fact correct these version of ruby on rails works perfectly on Postgres <= 9.4 @lucas

Answer (score 1):

In the `.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/active_record-4.1.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb` file, Change the value of `client_min_messages` to anything other than `panic`. The valid values can be - debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1, log, notice, warning, error.

The issue is with the newer versions of Postgresql adapter in ActiveRecord where `panic` is the new and the default value and old Postgres versions do not support that.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I was using postgres 9.4.1 and upgraded to latest (12.1). Because of the version change, I got this issue. I reverted back to 9.4.1.  Is that same with you as well?

Comment: I believe you should able to upgrade to at least 9.6 version.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an "answer"

Answer (score 0):

In the given log says:-

*/Users/galaxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@folderName/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:274:in `client_min_messages='*

Go to the *schema statements.rb* file at line 274 and assign *`client_min_messages='* with any of these below values.

**debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1, log, notice, warning, error**

Answer (score 0):

No need to monkey patch or anything.
login to your postgresql via command line and create database from there and grant the privileges from there.

use the below command for this.

```
#to login
psql
#to create database
CREATE DATABASE super_awesome_application;
#grant the permission to the database for that user
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE super_awesome_application TO patrick;
#if you have not that user in you database create one 
CREATE USER sam WITH PASSWORD 'password';
#alter the role permission 
ALTER ROLE sam WITH SUPERUSER;
```