# How to I resolve this Postgresql Invalid Paramater error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am running the rake db:create command from my command line and it is giving me the following error:

```
2020-02-29 15:22:21.033 GMT [39162] ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": "panic"
2020-02-29 15:22:21.033 GMT [39162] HINT:  Available values: debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1, log, notice, warning, error.
2020-02-29 15:22:21.033 GMT [39162] STATEMENT:  SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": "panic"
HINT:  Available values: debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1, log, notice, warning, error.
: SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
```

Postgresql version is 9.4.26

database.yml file extract is

```
development:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  database: my_database
  password: my_database
```

I would really appreciate anyone who has dealt with this before pointing me in the right direction. From what I can see, I need to amend the pg_config to disallow the 'Panic' variable but can't find any guidance on how to do this.

Comment: Have you seen this question? Seems like it could be a similar issue, might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58763542/3536464

Comment: Yes seen that and tried the solutions suggested. Mainly a monkey patch which hasn't worked for me and the versionf of postgres which also wasn't the issue. Thanks though!

Comment: Ah, sorry it couldn't help you! I'm stumped as well, good luck getting to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to get passed this issue:

This method in the `postgresql_adapter.rb` file:

```rb
    def set_standard_conforming_strings
        old, self.client_min_messages = client_min_messages, 'panic'
        execute('SET standard_conforming_strings = on', 'SCHEMA') rescue nil
    ensure
        self.client_min_messages = old
    end
```

needs amending too:

```rb
    def set_standard_conforming_strings
        old, self.client_min_messages = client_min_messages, 'error'
        execute('SET standard_conforming_strings = on', 'SCHEMA') rescue nil
    ensure
        self.client_min_messages = old
    end
```

How to find:

```sh
gem info pg
```

`cd` to location - for me this was:

```sh
cd /Users/williammurphy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4
```

then:

```sh
grep -ri 'panic' .
```

change anything that is set to 'panic' to 'error' instead and this should see you through.