# Ruby on the Rails - Puma Server errors not providing much after Heroku scheduled maintance

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, puma

Heroku did scheduled database maintenance and now app is down.  Returning 500 status.    
   I am unable to determine the issue from the logs.

Ruby -v 2.3.1
Puma Server
Postgre -v 12.5 
The stack was EOL (cedar-14) but I upgraded to Heroku-16.  Still same issue
Any help is appreciated.  I am hitting a wall.

```
2020-12-13T18:06:49.168269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.XXXXXXXXX.com request_id=5dfab114-cd68-4b1b-8818-141f9c293ea6 fwd="66.249.89.94,172.69.63.169" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=58ms status=500 bytes=1714 protocol=https
2020-12-13T18:06:49.100995+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 172.69.63.169 at 2020-12-13 18:06:49 +0000
2020-12-13T18:06:49.126184+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": "panic"
2020-12-13T18:06:49.126185+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  Available values: debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1, log, notice, warning, error.
2020-12-13T18:06:49.126186+00:00 app[web.1]: : SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.154501+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": "panic"
2020-12-13T18:06:49.154503+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  Available values: debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1, log, notice, warning, error.
2020-12-13T18:06:49.154504+00:00 app[web.1]: : SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157054+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157055+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": "panic"
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157056+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  Available values: debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1, log, notice, warning, error.
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157056+00:00 app[web.1]: : SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'):
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157057+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157073+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157073+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `block in log'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157074+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157074+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:460:in `log'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157075+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157075+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:275:in `client_min_messages='
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157075+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:313:in `set_standard_conforming_strings'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157076+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:677:in `configure_connection'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157076+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:658:in `connect'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157076+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157077+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157077+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157078+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157078+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157078+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157079+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157079+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157080+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157080+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157080+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157081+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157081+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157081+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157082+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157082+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157090+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157090+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157091+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157096+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157096+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157096+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157097+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157097+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157097+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157098+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157098+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157098+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157099+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157099+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157099+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157100+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157100+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157100+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157100+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157101+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157101+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157101+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157102+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157102+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157103+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157103+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157103+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157104+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157104+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157104+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157105+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157105+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-13T18:06:49.157105+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: Did you see this question and the answer to it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763542/pginvalidparametervalue-error-invalid-value-for-parameter-client-min-messag Btw you are on an old version of Rails that reached EOL and is unsupported. I advise for updating your application because you will probably experience more incompatibilities in the near future.

Comment: [The Heroku-16 stack is also deprecated](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#stack-support-details) and will only receive support for another four months. I suggest moving to Heroku-18 or, better yet, Heroku-20. Living on the trailing end of just-barely-supported-to-end-of-life isn't a sound strategy.

Comment: You are looking at the exception. `panic` is not a valid diagnostic level. You probably need to upgrade or downgrade something to fix.